# How push history router without change URL

Tags: url, next.js, next-router, next-link

For example I have a form with three steps. I want that each step are in the history router but without changing de URL

Is it possible do it with Next Route or Next Link?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to hide query params from the URL while using router.push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70484870/how-to-hide-query-params-from-the-url-while-using-router-push)?

Comment: No, the URL doesn't change but the history is not pushed @juliomalves